# Creating a composite index shifts a 69 row index merge to a 441 row ref query

Tags: mysql

embarking on the journey of composite indexes in MySQL. Prior, I was only using newbie single-column indexes, which had poor results. Composite indexes have dramatically increased performance in a very short amount of time.

That said, sometimes I can't quite figure out if there is an improvement or not in situations where the row scan goes UP after the query type improves.

I will include the initial table def and indexes at the bottom to reduce clutter.

So let's take this query:

```
SELECT MAX(`rtm_psa_appointment`.updated_at)
FROM `rtm_psa_appointment`
INNER JOIN `rtm_user` ON `rtm_user`.id = `rtm_psa_appointment`.user_id
INNER JOIN `rtm_psa_entity` ON `rtm_psa_entity`.id = `rtm_psa_appointment`.resource_id
WHERE (`rtm_user`.`id`=106) AND (`rtm_psa_entity`.`id`=456968)
```

Before testing with a composite index, my EXPLAIN results showed an index_merge:

[explain with single-column indexes only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZpFI.png)

I then created a composite index on rtm_psa_appointment: (resource_id, user_id, id) while removing the single column index (resource_id). My query type improves from an index_merge to a ref:

[with composite index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwD4q.png)

*SIDE NOTE: during testing i didn't change the index name from a previous attempt; i just noticed, so wanted to clarify in case of any confusion. that comp index does contain (resource_id,user_id,id) even though the idx name doesn't its contents.*

But notice that my scanned rows goes from 1x1x69 to 1x1x414.

My thinking was that the scan was for max(updated_at), so I changed my comp index to (resource_id,user_id,updated_at,id). This did not improve anything, so I still have a ref query with 1x1x414 rows scanned.

So I'm unclear, is this an improvement over the index_merge or is the index_merge better in this situation?

```
CREATE TABLE `rtm_psa_appointment` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `uuid` VARCHAR(36) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `oplock` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `user_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `updated_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `deleted_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `deleted_by` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `is_deleted` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `created_by` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_by` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `psa_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `psa_created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `psa_last_mod_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `start_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `end_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `title` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `description` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `resource_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `entity` JSON NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `created_at` (`created_at`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `updated_at` (`updated_at`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `deleted_at` (`deleted_at`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `deleted_by` (`deleted_by`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `is_deleted` (`is_deleted`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `oplock` (`oplock`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `psa_created_at` (`psa_created_at`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `psa_last_mod_at` (`psa_last_mod_at`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `start_at` (`start_at`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `end_at` (`end_at`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `resource_id` (`resource_id`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `rtm_psa_appointment_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `forge`.`rtm_user` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT `rtm_psa_appointment_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`resource_id`) REFERENCES `forge`.`rtm_psa_entity` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=44203
;
```

Comment: Keep in mind the row estimates in EXPLAIN are very rough. They don't have to be accurate, they only have to be close enough to influence the optimizer's choice of which index to use.

Answer (score 0):

Three tables are JOINed, but two of them are effectively unused.  Why not simply say this?

```
SELECT  MAX(updated_at)
    FROM  `rtm_psa_appointment`
    WHERE  user_id = 106
      AND  resource_id = 456968
```

and have this composite index:

```
INDEX(user_id,  resource_id,   -- either order
      updated_at)              -- last
```

There is a *possible* reason for JOINing. The JOINs make sure that the corresponding rows *exist* in the other tables.  The Index above still applies.

(I am assuming that each table has `PRIMARY KEY(id)`.)

More on designing composite indexes:  [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

"Index merge intersect" is almost always worse than a suitable "composite" (multi-column) index.  ("Index merge union" is a different situation.)

And, yes, it may be important to Drop `INDEX(a)` when Adding `INDEX(a,b)`.  Did you do this when you got disappointing results for the 4-column attempt?  Check the index name against its definition.

The 'name' of an index is virtually useless; don't worry about it.  (Except for the use above.)